# basis for topological spaces.....

Tags: general-topology

When we say that the sets $(a,b)$  form a base for usual topology on  $\mathbb R$ why do we say in that context that $a,b$ are rational? Why not irrrational?

And if we take only open intervals then that is also a base for usual topology (or not?).

Also what is a base of the discrete topology on the real line...?

Comment: The set of intervals with rational endpoints is one basis for the topology on $\mathbb{R}$. The set of intervals with irrational endpoints is another basis. And the set of intervals $(a,b)$ with arbitrary endpoints is yet another basis. So as you can see, there can be many different bases for the same topology. Different bases can have different applications, so the possibility of many different bases can be useful.

Answer (score 4):

One might as well take $a$ anf $b$ irrational. However the set of $(a,b)$ with $a,b\in \mathbf Q$ is a *countable* basis for the usual (order) topology on $\mathbf R$. It is because of this existence of a countable basis that we have sequential characterisations of limit, continuity, compacity, &c.

It is not the only countable basis for the topology of $\mathbf R$: you also may take for $a,b$ dyadic fractions (with denominator a power of $2$), for instance.

As for a basis  of the discrete topology, as points are open, you have $\mathbf R$ itself.

Comment: (a b)  a, b£Q is countable??  Intervals are uncountable